# UnboundLocalError. Why has this occurred?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sqlite

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student, Behaviour")
data = c.fetchall() #'data' is a tuple and cannot be altered
l = []
for i in data: #for individual records in the whole database do:
    record = str(i)
    record = record.replace("u'","")
    record = record.replace("'", "")
    record = record.replace('"', '')
    record = record.replace("(","")
    record = record.replace(")", "")
    Formattedrecord = record.replace(","," -")
l.append(Formattedrecord)
```

This returns the error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Formattedrecord' referenced before assignment
But I do not understand why, can somebody help?

Comment: Indent the last line to be part of the loop. You got the `UnboundLocalError` because `data` is empty, but if it *wasn't* empty you only append the *last* entry to `l`.

Comment: Why are you turning `record` to `str()` here, then replace all the quotes? Perhaps you want to add `' - '.join(i)` *instead*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care with indentation:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student, Behaviour")
data = c.fetchall() #'data' is a tuple and cannot be altered
l = []
for i in data: #for individual records in the whole database do:
    record = str(i)
    record = record.replace("u'","")
    record = record.replace("'", "")
    record = record.replace('"', '')
    record = record.replace("(","")
    record = record.replace(")", "")
    Formattedrecord = record.replace(","," -")
    l.append(Formattedrecord) # this should be part of the for loop
```

Comment: The OP probably *does not* want to use `str(i)`; by the looks of it, `Formattedrecord = ' - '.join(i)` would be more appropriate.